# Get the general route in rendered controller

Tags: twig, symfony5

html.twig I am rendering a path like this :

```
{{ render(path('plugintabs')) }}
```

In the controller linked to this route if I `$request->attributes->get('_route')` it will return me **'plugintabs'** but I want the global route (the one my browser shows me in the URL bar)

The best would be to have the route and not the route name.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->container->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest()->get('_route');
```

Was the solution for the name

and

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
```

for the route